# Exclude certain elements from being animated in android layout transitions

Tags: android, android-animation, layouttransition

I have a question regarding the android layout transition framework. In particular i want to achieve an effect that a certain part of an layout slides down or up depending on the visibility of another view(s).

Imagine the following layout. (And please overlook the nested LinearLayouts here ;) )

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
                android:id="@+id/changingView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        <View
                android:id="@+id/changingView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/movingView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now what i want to achieve is that when **changingView1** and **changingView2** change their visibility that **movingView** slides up or down.

By enabling the **LayoutTransition.CHANGING** for the parent layout the sliding part works fine so. But this has the side effect that the **movingView** will also be animated when there are being items added or removed because this layout changes its bounds. And here lies my problem because this results in a very strange looking animation.

So back to my question. Is there a way to keep the sliding animation without animating layout bound changes on the **movingView**?

Disabling layoutTransitions on the **movingView** obviously does not help because this only effects the animations of the child views. I also tried playing around with enabling and disabling different LayoutTransitions on the parent layout but so far without the desired effect.

If i can add more details please let me know otherwise i hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I know it's late but hope it can help someone. Since `android:animateLayoutChanges` is the property of the direct parent, you can wrap your `View`/`Layout` in a `FrameLayout` (or some other `ViewGroup`) and set `android:animateLayoutChanges="false"` on the new parent.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid unwanted animations you can remove the animate layout changes by code when needed, something like this:

```
//removing the animate layout changes to prevent the default animation for the newly added items
parentLayout.setLayoutTransition(null);

/* do some logic to add the new views */

//add the animate layout changes back so the over changes will be still animated
new Handler().post(() -> {parentLayout.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());});
```